# Apache server document root in linux

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, php

I have to find code of websites from customer's Linux Ubuntu server . I have checked their default-document root that is .

```
/var/www/localhost/htdocs
```

I just found there many html files (e.g index.html.en , index.html.fr,index.html.ce, index.html.ft) but not whole website code like php script.

These files are located in `/etc/apache2/`

```
httpd.conf  
magic  
modules.d  
ssl  
vhosts.d
```

Where would the php script files be? Or could you suggest me any way for me to find them. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all there was file name as httpd.conf where custom directory was defined like

```
  etc /.../vhosts.d/*conf
```

vhosts.d files had 3 conf files . one of them was related to my code . server-name and rewriterule were defined there. like

```
  /virtualhosts/aalm/ecash3/....www/
```

i got target files in www.

Answer (score 0):

Does `a2query -s` show something? It should list enabled sites. Usually the site-config should be under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site.conf`, symlinked to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site.conf`, if the site is enabled.

Maybe the function `phpinfo();` helps you

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

It sould list information about the webserver. In the section Apache environment the document root should be listed

Comment: a2query -s command not found . and under these files(sites-available,sites.conf) are not existing under  /etc/apache2/ . please anymore help or tricks

Comment: If sites-enabled is not there it could also be in `/etc/apache2/http.conf`. Check the bottom lines: maybe someone put a custom directory there.

Comment: yes you said right . there is line at end 
Include /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/*.conf

Comment: @Rinzwind there are 3 conf files under /vhosts.d/ directory

Comment: and one of them conf files has these lines . its means RewriteRule is like document root .                                                                         RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^ecash-staging.atlas-lms.com(:\d+)?$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /virtualhosts/aalm/ecash3.0/ecash_aalm/www/$1 [L]
.